# How to get every first/second/third/fourth/last week of wednesday of current month

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me, I want to compare few events that fall with in first week of tuesday/wednesday in current month.

Please provide stuff for below one,

1. First week of monday in current month
2. Second week of any day in current month
3. third week of any day in current month
4. fourth of any day in current month
5. last week of any day in current month

It can be php or mysql. Please help me waiting for your support.

Comment: What things have you tried so far and what went wrong (or right)?

Comment: `Please provide stuff for below one` Budget?

Comment: i have to tried to get date for first week of monday of current month and tried code are, $tc = strtotime('1st monday', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1) ); print '<P/>The first monday of this month is ' . date("Y/m/d", $tc); $tc = strtotime('1st monday', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')+1, 1) );print '<P/>The first monday of next month is ' . date("Y/m/d", $tc); 

$tc = strtotime('3rd monday', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')+1, 1) );
print '<P/>The third monday of next month is ' . date("Y/m/d", $tc);

Comment: But no luck, please take me correct path

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime). It will accepts *relative time strings* as an argument.

For instance,

```
strtotime('next monday');
```

Comment: i have found this code and was not giving correct data, $tc = strtotime('1st monday', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1) );
print '<P/>The first monday of this month is ' . date("Y/m/d", $tc);

$tc = strtotime('1st monday', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')+1, 1) );
print '<P/>The first monday of next month is ' . date("Y/m/d", $tc);

$tc = strtotime('2nd monday', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')+1, 1) );
print '<P/>The second monday of next month is ' . date("Y/m/d", $tc);

$tc = strtotime('3rd monday', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')+1, 1) );
print '<P/>The third monday of next month is ' . date("Y/m/d", $tc);

Comment: let me try, is it possible to identify the monday is in first week of current month or not. if yes, please tell me, how to find and which date is falling. plz